# R ensure that `sys.call()` information is always evaluated

Tags: r

I want to use the output of a `sys.call()` in a function that is being called from a wrapper function. I cannot change the fact that there is a sys.call, but I need to find a way to make the code below function anyway.

We have a top wrapper function, which calls a secondary function, and just a logical statement saved in a variable in the global environment:

```r
test_fun1 <- function(x = hello){
  test_fun2(cond = x)
}

hello <- TRUE
```

So let's look at this secondary function and define it like this and execute it:

### Case 1

```
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  call$cond
}
```

So when I evaluate the `test_fun1` with the value stored in the `hello` variable:

```
test_fun1(hello)
```

I do not get the evaluated value of the `hello` value but it gives me the output:

```r
x
```

### Case 2

Now when I use the `eval()` function with its default, I get an error that the variable `x` is not found:

```r
# Case 2
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond)
}

test_fun1(hello)
> Error in eval(call$cond) : object 'x' not found
```

### Case 3

So it's clear that I need to deal with the different environments. So I modify the option in the `eval` function:

```r
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond, envir = 1)
}

test_fun1(hello)
TRUE
```

### New challenge for Case 3

But now when you wrap the wrapper function in yet another function, this approach does not work again either:

```r
test_fun3 <- function(y){
  test_fun1(x = y)
}

test_fun3(y = hello)
```

And we would need:

### Solution for new problem with case 3

```r
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond, envir = 2)
}
test_fun3(y = hello)
```

Now here is essentially my question:
**Can I automate this `envir` (or use a different way to evaluate the call) argument so that the call argument is always evaluated, no matter how many functions are called above it?**

Many thanks

## Full code

```r
test_fun1 <- function(x = hello){
  test_fun2(cond = x)
}

hello <- TRUE

# Case 1
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  call$cond
}

test_fun1(hello)

# Case 2
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond)
}

test_fun1(hello)



# Case 3
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond, envir = 1)
}

test_fun1(hello)



# Problem with Case 3
test_fun3 <- function(y){
  test_fun1(x = y)
}

test_fun3(y = hello)


# Solution for Problem with Case 3
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  eval(call$cond, envir = 2)
}
test_fun3(y = hello)
```

Comment: This seems problematic. You are essentially trying to alter the way R resolves variables. R uses lexical scoping by default so variables are searched where functions are defined, not where they are invoked. Since that's fundamentally not how the language was designed that's going to be messy. Perhaps using something `rlang::quo` to create a quosure which captures not only variables but environments can help. Also `formula`s in R can capture environments as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I automate this envir (or use a different way to evaluate the
> call) argument so that the call argument is always evaluated, no
> matter how many functions are called above it?

seems like you are wanting to set an environment number one less the length of the current stack length.

```
  eval(call$cond, envir = length(sys.calls()) -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `dynGey(deparse(call$cond))`. It will look the variable in `call$cond` up going through the environments in the call stack. This might have unwanted effects.

```r
# Case 3
test_fun2 <- function(cond){
  call <- sys.call()
  dynGet(deparse(call$cond))
}
```